# MySQL swap one table for another?

Tags: post-thumbnails, mysql, sql, table

So I have a situation with this WordPress site I'm doing where I have to swap the positions of my featured images. I have two per post thanks to the Multiple Post Thumbnails plugin, but now whatever is the first Featured Image now needs to be the second and whatever is the second needs to be the first.

So there's 300 posts already so swapping out them manually is going to be time consuming. I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this using some kind of statement in MySQL to swap these two out. Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Adam, if you find my answer useful please up-vote it and mark as selected. Thank you.

Comment: The title says "swap one *table* for another" but the question implies swapping values among *rows*.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Basically, you're right, Michael. But it could have gone either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a php script ( `fpw-swap-thumbnails.php` ) with the code below and put it in root of your site:

```
<?php
// load WordPress environment
require( 'wp-load.php' );

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' ),
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

// get all published posts of type specified in $args
$posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    // get thumbnails ids
    $thmbsArray = array(
        get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true ),
        get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_secondary-image_thumbnail_id', true )
    ); 
    // if both thumbnails exist then swap their values
    if ( ( '' != $thmbsArray[ 0 ] ) && ( '' != $thmbsArray[ 1 ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', $thmbsArray[ 1 ] );
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_secondary-image_thumbnail_id', $thmbsArray[ 0 ] );
    }
}
?>
```

**NOTE:** in `post_secondary-image_thumbnail_id` replace `secondary-image` with your registered secondary image id. In `$args` add any extra post types into `post_type` array.

Make a backup of your database ( just to be safe ). Execute the script. Check results. Remove the script.

Comment: This will change all the references everywhere....including custom post types?

Comment: Also, I noticed nothing in the script about calling a specific database. Usually they do, or does it just take the info from wp-config.php instead?

Comment: You didn't mention custom posts in your question. I'll edit the answer to include posts of any type. The table names are not explicitly stated but it uses two tables - posts and postmeta in your website's database.

Comment: Seems to be throwing an error at line 7 which would be  'post_type => array( 'post', 'page' ),

Comment: Never mind....it's was missing a closing ' in post_type.

Comment: You are right. I'm editing the answer to correct it.

Comment: Ran the script, but all I got was a blank, white screen and nothing swapped once I started checking the pages.

Comment: Check my NOTE about meta key for the second thumbnail. Blank screen is correct as this scripts does not display anything.

Comment: So my id is 'thumbnail-second' so I should be using post_thumbnail-second_thumbnail_id like this example?

$thmbsArray = array(
        get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true ),
        get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_thumbnail-second_thumbnail_id', true )
    );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25421/discussion-between-frank-p-walentynowicz-and-adam-bell).